# Ошибки при билде проекта в Unity3d

Tags: unity3d

[image: На не выделенные ошибки можно не обращать внимания]
В процессе эмуляции и исполнении кода данных скриптов всё в порядке, но при **построении** внезапно ругается на пространство имён UnityEditor и UnityEditorInternal и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы используете пространство имен Editor в файлах, которые пойдут в билд, а оно перед билдом отключается. Вот и получаете ошибки компиляции.
Полагаю, у вас там какой-то кастомный редактор для класса. Создайте подпапку Editor там, где сейчас лежит этот класс редактора и положите сам туда.
Всё, что лежит в папках Editor(их может быть сколько угодно по проекту) не пойдёт в билд.